# How to identify who made changes in SQL server management?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm working on the server using SQL Server Management Studio 2005. Is it possible to identify the person who made changes in the SQL server Management Studio 2005 tables data?

Comment: By default, SQL Server doesn't track such information.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "we can't answer it"!

Comment: really? i try this codes

Comment: SELECT [name]
  FROM sys.databases;

USE SalesReport;

SELECT *
  FROM fn_my_permissions(null, 'DATABASE')
yet nothing happend

Comment: If you want to add more to your question, use the `edit` link below it. That would also let you format your code (using the `{}` button) - as you may have noticed, code in comments isn't very readable.

Comment: `fn_my_permissions` tells you what you're allowed to do right now. It a) doesn't tell you whether you've exercised any of those permissions recently, nor does it b) tell you what permissions you had 5 minutes ago. (And similar comments for other functions that let you view others permissions). So I don't see how it helps with "identify the person who made changes" which is a question about things in the past.

Comment: i can see it now, many thanks bud, cheers!!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "SQL Server Management Studio 2005 tables"? I don't think that management studio creates its own tables, so which data are you talking about?

Comment: stop free access to the sql server to prevent a "strange" (anybody) access  in the future.

Comment: You could create triggers on the inserts/updates/deletes. There will be a performance trade-off though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to log the data in some way manually.  My favorite is to include CREATE and UPDATE columns on each table as such:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD [CREATE_TIMESTAMP] datetime NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD [CREATE_USERID] varchar(30) NULL DEFAULT (suser_sname())
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD [UPDATE_TIMESTAMP] datetime NULL DEFAULT (getdate())
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD [UPDATE_USERID] varchar(30) NULL DEFAULT (suser_sname())
```

Then add a trigger to force the update of the UPDATE columns.
After that you can tell who inserted or updated a row.  Still can't tell a delete though. You would need a log table for that.  Basically create a table `TableName_Log` that has the same structure as `TableName` then a DELETE trigger that moves the deleted rows (updated too if you want) into the log table.